# Scipy minimize with contraints and bounds in output

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize

I'm working with a General Equlibrium model. I'm trying to minimize an objective function to get the productivity in each sector of economy. I have two main functions, `equilibrium`, and `obj`. The input of the `equilibrium` function is x1, that is the productivity of each i sectores. The main output of this function is the share of workers (L_m). The share of workers for all i is positive and the sum is the unity.
So I need find x1 that minimize my objective function `obj`and satisfies the restrictions in L_m.

I make the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Define parameters of function

def pars():
    
    i = 10
    theta = 3
    w = np.ones(i).reshape(i, 1)
    L = np.ones(i).reshape(i, 1)
    beta = np.random.uniform(low = 1e-4, high = 0.99, size = (100, 1)).reshape(10, 10)
    sigma =  np.random.uniform(low = 1e-3, high = 0.91, size = (i, 1))
    VA_d = np.random.uniform(low = 1e-3, high = 1, size = (i, 1))
    x1 = np.random.uniform(low = 1e-3, high = 30, size = (i, 1))

    return [theta, w, i, L, beta, sigma, VA_d, x1]

[theta, w, i, L, beta, sigma, VA_d, x1] = pars()



def equlibrium(x1, beta, sigma):
    
    sig1 = 1 - sigma 
    phi = np.multiply(np.power(sig1, sigma), np.power(sigma, sigma) ) 
    
    # Bp matrix
    id = np.eye(i)
    fid = id == 1
    
    Bp = np.multiply(beta.T, sig1).T
    Bp[fid] = Bp[fid] - 1
    Bp = np.multiply(-1, Bp)
    
    # D object
    
    W = np.log(np.divide(w, np.multiply(phi, x1) ) )
    K = np.multiply(sig1, np.sum( np.multiply(beta, np.log(beta) ), axis = 1).reshape(i, 1) )
    D = W - K
    
    # prices
    
    log_p = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(Bp), D)
    p = np.exp(log_p)

    #### Objects B and G

    # Object B
    
    B = np.multiply(np.divide(sig1, sigma), np.divide(beta, p.T) ) 
       
    # Object G
    
    g1 = np.power(np.divide(sig1, sigma), sig1)    
    g2 =  np.prod( np.power(np.divide(beta, p.T), np.multiply(beta, sig1) ), axis = 1 ).reshape(i, 1) 
    G = np.multiply(x1, np.multiply(g1, g2))
    
    #### consumption

    c1 = np.divide(1, np.power(p, theta)) 
    c2 = np.divide(np.multiply(w, L), np.sum(np.power(p, (1 - theta) ) ) )
    
    C = np.multiply(c1, c2)
     
    #### B e C divided by G
    
    B_til = np.divide(B, G.T) # retirei o transposto do G
    C_til = np.divide(C, G)
        
    ##### labor
    
    L_m = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.eye(i) - B_til.T), C_til)
    #L_m = L_m/np.sum(L_m)   # a soma de L_i = L = 1
    
    ##### calcular o X e o  Q
        
    X = np.multiply(B, L_m)
    Q = np.multiply(G, L_m)
    
    ####### ADDED VALUE
    VA_m = np.divide(np.multiply(p, C), L_m)
    
    ###### Eq solve
    
    #EQ_solve = np.multiply(np.multiply(p, sig1), np.multiply(beta, np.divide(G, B)) ) - p
                                      
    return [p, C, B, G, L_m, VA_m]
```

My objective function is:

```
def obj1(x1):
    
    x1 = x1.reshape(i, 1)
        
    [p, C, B, G, L_m, VA_m] =  equlibrium(x1 = x1, beta = beta, sigma = sigma)
    #Q - C - X.sum(1).reshape(i, 1) = np.zeros(i).reshape(i, 1)
    
    obj = np.sum( np.power(np.divide((VA_m - VA_d), VA_m), 2) )
    obj = np.log(obj)    
     
    return obj


def callback(x1):
    global cc
    cc += 1
    fobj = obj1(x1)
    print(f'\033[1;033mObjetivo: {np.around(fobj, 8)}, iter: {cc}')
```

First I use `L-BFGS-B` algorithm, and in `equilibrium` function I put `L_m = L_m/np.sum(L_m)`. This works well in optimization, but, the equilibrium `np.multiply(G, L_m) - np.multiply(B, L_m) - C` has to be zero. And proceeding in this way, it does not happen.

```
cc = 0
Bd = ( (1e-1, 1000), )*i

sol = minimize(obj1, x1, method='L-BFGS-B', bounds = Bd, tol = 1e-20, callback = callback, options={'maxiter':300, 'maxls':1e5, 'maxfun':1e10, 'maxcor': 4000, 'eps': 1e-10})
```

So I made a constraint and switched the algorithm to `SLSQP`.

```
def restr(x1):
    [p, C, B, G, L_m, VA_m] = equlibrium(x1, beta, sigma)

    return np.sum(L_m) - 1


cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x1: restr(x1) } )

sol = minimize(obj1, x1, method='trust-constr', constraints = cons, bounds=Bd,  options = {'maxiter':5000} )
```

However, that definitely didn't work. It seems that the algorithm was successful in optimizing, but it did not respect the constraints. How to proceed to solve this problem?

Comment: Never seen CGE models solved with scipy.  Economists use different tools (also real CGE models are large scale).

Comment: Scipy has many aplications in economics and CGE models. See Python Programming for Economics and Finance from Quantecon.

Comment: Much better see what professional economists do compared to undergraduate students: https://www.elsevier.com/books/handbook-of-computable-general-equilibrium-modeling/dixon/978-0-444-53634-1

Comment: If you have a better solution than scipy I'll be happy to know. The book looks interesting, I'll check it out.

Comment: Most CGE models (especially trade related) I am aware of are in GAMS or Gempack. DSGE is a very different matter. They use different tools.

Comment: In addition to Erwin's comment: Your code is overly verbose (and inefficient). For instance, phi, Bp, W, K, D and the prices don't depend on your optimization variable x1. Thus, you only need to compute this matrices once outside your objective. Using the overloaded arithmetic operators for NumPy arrays instead of the verbose functions makes it easier to read too, i.e. `np.log(w / (phi * x1))` instead of `np.log(np.divide(w, np.mulitply(phi, x1)))` is *way* easier to read. Furthermore, you should try to avoid computing inverses whenever possible, solve a linear system instead.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that your initial guess `x1` is (very likely) not feasible and contradicts your equality constraints. You should always start with a feasible initial guess (that isn't computed randomly btw).

Comment: @joni See the balance function is different from the objective one and that phi, Bp, W, K, D are used to calculate p. Also, numpy's functions for multiplying and dividing are pretty intuitive to me and work well for large matrices and Scipy's optimization functions. As for the initial guess, it must be within the bounds, and satisfy the constraints. However, this is just a simple example of a much larger problem, and I didn't actually check that the initial guess satisfied the constraint.